# Is there a way i can store this variable without it getting reset

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have this recursive function

```
def recursive_search(x):
    y = []
    for i in x:
        if (i == tuple(i)) or (i == list(i)) or i == set(i):
            recursive_search(i)
        else:
            y.append(i)
    print(y)
print(recursive_search(("re",("cur",("sion",(" ",("foo",["bar",{"baz"}])))))))
```

which prints out

```
['baz']
['bar']
['foo']
[' ']
['sion']
['cur']
['re']
None
```

when i set "print(y)" to "return y" it only prints out "['re']". if using global y is unsafe then what is another way i could do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the return value and using that to construct your answer:

```
def recursive_search(x):
    y = []
    for i in x:
        if type(i) in (tuple, list, set):
            y.append(recursive_search(i))
        else:
            y.append(i)
    return y

print(recursive_search(("re",("cur",("sion",(" ",("foo",["bar",{"baz"}])))))))
# ['re', ['cur', ['sion', [' ', ['foo', ['bar', ['baz']]]]]]]
```

If you need something other than nesting you can do something else with the return.

Comment: I think `y+=recursive_search(i)` may be more appropriate because I think the op wants a resulting array that's flat.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable.. it was unclear what the OP wanted as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the second argument, which will be every time that the recursive function is called:

```
def recursive_search(x,y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = []
    for i in x:
        if (i == tuple(i)) or (i == list(i)) or i == set(i):
            recursive_search(i, y)
        else:
            y +=[i]
    return y[:]

y = recursive_search(("re",("cur",("sion",(" ",("foo",["bar",{"baz"}]))))))
print(y)
z = recursive_search(("a",("brown",("fox",("jumps ",("over",["foo",{"bar"}]))))))
print(z)

['re', 'cur', 'sion', ' ', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['a', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps ', 'over', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: You will only be able to call this function once. The side effect persists over multiple invocations.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited with possible workaround. But may not optimal.

Comment: Edited one more time.